# php ldap user password change ldap_modify ldap_mod_replace

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Which function should I use for when a user wants to change his password in active directory, using php?

They would be binding to the server with their current username and password, then inputting a new password to make that change.

I used ldap_mod_replace before, but I had to use an AD account with higher privileges to replace their password with a new one.

I also tried ldap_modify, but it said the user had invalid credentials, even though the user and password binded.

*New passwords are encoded properly.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are changed via LDAP in one of two ways:

- transmit a modify request to the server
- transmit a password modify extended request to server (requires the current password)

The modify request has the following parameters: distinguished name to change, and a list of modifications. The only connection the modify request has to the current authentication state of the connection is that permission to issue a modify request to the server (modern, professional-quality directory servers can disallow operations by authentication state of the connection) and whether the authentication state is permitted to modify the entry identified by the distinguished name (which might be different from the authentication state). modify requests do not result in 'invalid credentials', only bind requests (which set the authentication state of the connection) can result in 'invalid credentials'. If the authentication state is not permitted to change its own password, then an authentication state with those permissions must be used.